# Assign array of items to selected item - Many to Many relationship in core data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm working on an iOS app with Core Data and Swift 5.5
I have 2 entities ( Category ) and ( Item ) and I created a Many-to-Many relationship between those entities, so in Category, it has ( items ) and in Item, it has ( categories ).

now I want to assign multiple items to selected Categrory so I tried this code but it didn't work

```
var selectedItems = [Item]()

let category = selectedCategory
category.items = selectedItems

do {
  try moc.save()
} catch {
  print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

This way working well in One-To-Many relationships but in Many-To-Many it didn't work.
So how I can fix this issue or how I can assign an array of selected items to a specific category?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of writing to the property you should use one of the generated add (or remove) methods. If the relationship is named `items` you should have two method `addToItems` for adding a single or multiple `Item`

So try

```
 category.addToItems(NSSet(array: selectedItems))
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this method but it accepts only one item, I tried to pass an array of Items but it's given me this error below:


No exact matches in call to instance method 'addToItems'

Comment: Use a `for` loop to add each item

Comment: @AdelBassiony it takes a Set when adding multiple objects, I’ve updated the answer

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I tried it with the updated solution but I got the same error ( No exact matches in call to instance method 'addToItems' )

Comment: The relationship name is `items`?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes

Comment: @AdelBassiony Ah, sorry the parameter type is NSSet and not Set and there is no automatic cast. I  will update the answer

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yea, Thank you 